# ExpandableListView OnClick change activity

Tags: android, onclick, expandablelistview, onclicklistener

my question is simple but I am not able to solve it. I have got ExpandableListView and I just want to on my childs item click go to the SecondActivity(When I click America go to the SecondActivity, same Brazil etc..).
The toast message works pretty good but I want to go to the SecondActivity OnClick, when I tryed go like this `Intent intent0 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SecondActivity.class); startActivity(intent0);` it does not works..

I am a little bit confuse of this code, can someone say what I must change in this code to solve that problem?
I am newbie, thank you very much!:)

Here is my MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends ExpandableListActivity{

    private ArrayList<String> parentItems = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayList<Object> childItems = new ArrayList<Object>();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // this is not really  necessary as ExpandableListActivity contains an ExpandableList
        //setContentView(R.layout.main);


        ExpandableListView expandableList = getExpandableListView(); // you can use (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.list)

        expandableList.setDividerHeight(2);
        expandableList.setGroupIndicator(null);
        expandableList.setClickable(true);

        setGroupParents();
        setChildData();

        MyExpandableAdapter adapter = new MyExpandableAdapter(parentItems, childItems);

        adapter.setInflater((LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE), this);
        expandableList.setAdapter(adapter);
        expandableList.setOnChildClickListener(this);
    }

    public void setGroupParents() {
        parentItems.add("A");
        parentItems.add("B");
        parentItems.add("C");
        parentItems.add("D");
    }

    public void setChildData() {

        // A
        ArrayList<String> child = new ArrayList<String>();
        child.add("America");
        childItems.add(child);


        // B
        child = new ArrayList<String>();
        child.add("Brazil");
        childItems.add(child);

        // C
        child = new ArrayList<String>();
        child.add("Chile");
        childItems.add(child);


        // D
        child = new ArrayList<String>();
        child.add("Denmark");
        childItems.add(child);
    }

}
```

Here is my MyExpandableAdapter.java

```
public class MyExpandableAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private Activity activity;
    private ArrayList<Object> childtems;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private ArrayList<String> parentItems, child;


    public MyExpandableAdapter(ArrayList<String> parents, ArrayList<Object> childern) {
        this.parentItems = parents;
        this.childtems = childern;
    }

    public void setInflater(LayoutInflater inflater, Activity activity) {
        this.inflater = inflater;
        this.activity = activity;
    }


    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        child = (ArrayList<String>) childtems.get(groupPosition);

        TextView textView = null;

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.group, null);
        }

        textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        textView.setText(child.get(childPosition));

        convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(activity, child.get(childPosition),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
        }

        ((CheckedTextView) convertView).setText(parentItems.get(groupPosition));
        ((CheckedTextView) convertView).setChecked(isExpanded);

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return ((ArrayList<String>) childtems.get(groupPosition)).size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return parentItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public void onGroupCollapsed(int groupPosition) {
        super.onGroupCollapsed(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public void onGroupExpanded(int groupPosition) {
        super.onGroupExpanded(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return 0;
    }



    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }

}
```

Here is my group.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="40dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="39dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:textIsSelectable="true"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ExpandableListView
                android:id="@+id/list"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:groupIndicator="@null" />   

</LinearLayout>
```

Row.xml

```
<CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" 
    android:background="#CCFF99"
    />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try in your adapter getView instead of

```
 convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()...
```

something like

```
 textView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()...
```

**//EDIT**

```
textView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent intent0 = new Intent(activity, SecondActivity.class);
        activity.startActivity(intent0);
    }
});
```

Comment: I tryed it but still it does not work, It says:The method getApplicationContext() is undefined for the type new View.OnClickListener(){} When I try replace Toastmessage code to this code Intent intent0 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SecondActivity.class);
startActivity(intent0);

Comment: i fixed it ... see the EDIT .... insteat of convertview.setOn... paste there the code in edit ... i tried it on my phone and it works ...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try to override the method `onChildClick()` in your MainActivity and write the code to start the other activity there.

Comment: I tryed to replace this code expandableList.setOnChildClickListener(this); in MainActivity to this code expandableList.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() {
   
   @Override
   public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
     int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
    Intent intent0 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Vysledek.class); 
    startActivity(intent0);
    return false;
   }
  }); It does not work(application working but only toast message appear)

Comment: Have you tried to replace the first parameter of your intent when you are in your activity with this instead of getApplicationContext() (like this : Intent intent0 = new Intent(this, Vysledek.class);)?

Comment: it says: The constructor Intent(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener(){}, Class<Vysledek>) is undefined, any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry I forgot in this case this refers to the listener you are in so you should write MainActivity.this (Intent intent0 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Vysledek.class);).